# How to add an icon in my extension tab on the admin panel in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, admin

I'd like to add an icon like this image below, my custom module creates a new tab on this same route **Stores > Settings > Configuration**.

**So how can I add an icon like that red?**

[image: Magento 2 admin tabs with icon]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it looks like it might work.
Make the `system.xml`  look like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="section_id_here" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="400" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Section label here</label>
            <tab>tab_name_here</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::acl_name</resource>
            <class>my-custom-class</class>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Now you get a special class (`my-custom-class`) added to your section and you can control that via css files.

It works for tabs also but a bit different.
The class must be added as an attribute

```
   <tab id="tab_id_here" translate="label" sortOrder="400" class="my-tab-class">
        <label>Tab label</label>
    </tab>
```

Comment: not sure exactly what you needed so I added an answer for both sections and tabs.

Comment: Hello Marius thanks for you answer i am strucked where should I add css ?